# Unlock self login id

Tags: deployment

I have system admin profile. I am trying to connect to Sandbox(Developer Pro) from IDE Eclipse. My id is getting locked out and not able to connect and throwing login error. However I can connect to fullcopy sandbox from the IDE eclipse and create a project. I have 2 questions.

1. What could be the reason I can't connect to Developer-Pro Sandbox?

   - No login restriction - IP or login hours
   - I guess I have all the access. Is there any list of system access should I have ?
2. My Developer-Pro login id is keep getting locked out when I attempt to connect to Developer-pro from IDE Eclipse Kepler. Is there any way I can self unlock my id

Answer (score 0):

The developer org may be locked due to inactivity:

> Inactive Salesforce Developer Edition (DE) orgs are taking up space on instances, and due to capacity planning best practices, we will lock and eventually purge these inactive orgs.
>
> DE orgs that are inactive for 6 months or more may be locked, and DE orgs inactive for 365 days or more, may be purged. DE org admins will be notified by email if they are impacted.

You cannot self unlock, and you only have a week after the lock is set to open a case with customer support. To prevent this in the future, add a managed package to your org and install it elsewhere:

> An inactive DE org will not be locked if the user has created and uploaded a managed package, and that package is installed in another org. In other words, packaging orgs are exempt from this initiative.

**References**

- [Inactive Salesforce Developer Edition Orgs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231492&type=1)
- [Deactivate an Org](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_deactivate_org.htm&type=5)